# Portlets in Private pages in Liferay still viewable if user doesn't have role

Tags: liferay, portlet

So we want to set up a "default" private page layout for a user's private page with some portlets there by default. The issues is, not every user will have permission to view some of the default portlets. I took all of the permissions away from a portlet and it looks like it takes it away from the "Add" list, but if the portlet is already on the page, the user can still see it whether they have permission or not. Is there a way to fix this? As I understand it, a user is an administrator of their site by default, so we may be looking at this the wrong way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: crossreferencing https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/68682780 - please do this yourself next time (read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site). Plus, this question is not a good fit for stackoverflow, as it's not about programming - voting to close here, let's see if it gets attention on liferay.com